# error C2449 and error C2059

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a program about printing trapezoids with their length of top and bottom edges. But i can't execute my code to see if it's working. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);
{
    int top, bot, a, b;

    printf("Please enter the length of top:");
     scanf("%d", &top);
    printf("Please enter the length of bottom:");
     scanf("%d", &bot);

for(a = top; a < bot; a++) {
    for(b = top; b < a+1; b++) {
        printf("* ");}
    printf("\n");}
 return 0;
}
```

And here is my error texts:
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing `;` from the `int main(void)` function line, that is not a valid syntax

```
int main(void) // this is wrong here: ';'
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` after `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int main(void);
```

to

```
int main(void) //no semicolon
```